# Android Navstack Traversal

Tags: android, stack, traversal, nav

Is there a way to traverse the Activity or nav stack in android?  In ios you have the navigationController.viewControllers collection which lets you go through each one and call methods on them etc.  is there something similar to this in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, this is not supported. The "nav stack" in Android can contain activities from many different applications and processes.

Comment: ok, so then my follow up question for you: if you have say a stack of 5 activities open, all of which hit a rest service in one way or another.  then in the top most activity, you do some CRUD operation that might affect data that's still shown in the activities lower down the stack.  what do you recommend as the optimal way to update those activities (most of them list based) to reflect the changes made in the top activity?  one thought I had was to maintain a list of updates and pass them back via intent so they can be handled in onActivityResult, but that seemed a bit cumbersome. thoughts?

Comment: "what do you recommend as the optimal way to update those activities (most of them list based) to reflect the changes made in the top activity?" -- have them refresh their data in `onResume()`, as they return to the foreground. Nothing is needed before then.